# Use Computer headset like a hands-free for cell phone

Tags: 10.10, bluetooth, headphones, phone

Is it possible (and how) to use a computer headset (or speakers+mic) as a hands-free device for my mobile? I bought a bluetooth-dongle but I couldn't get it to work yet. I think I already set this up on an older version of Ubuntu on my laptop.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, the phone is an android 2.2 (but I think this doesn't matter) and the bluetooth device is a Integrated System Solution Corp. Bluetooth Device (according to lsusb).

[Output of lsusb -v](http://pastebin.com/H3yZi4KP)

EDIT:
I found a project that seams to do just what I want: [http://nohands.sourceforge.net](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/).
I tried to install it on my laptop but it didn't work. I'll try it again on my computer at home and post a description as soon as it works (or any of you guys could post a solution if you're faster;)

Edit2: I was able to connect my phone, but somehow the audio doesn't work. I think the program has troubles with pulseaudio, as the soundtest fails. Any ideas?

Edit3: I'm still trying to get this to work. I might buy another bluetooth dongle. ATM I'm able to dial numbers in hfconsole - that's all. Somehow I'm shure there is a way to get this to work!

Comment: good question. I'm not clear on what's the intended outcome here: does this mean you'd be able to use your computer headset simply connected to your android phone? And where does Ubuntu come into this equation? because if it's not, this thread is posted in the wrong forum.

Comment: The headset can't be connected to the phone directly. I want to use a bluetooth-connection between my phone and my computer that allows me to use my headset that's directly connected to my PC.

Comment: hah, weird idea, dude, but would like to see if you get an answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure it actually does matter which specific Android phone you have; not all Android phones have the same set of Blutooth profiles, so your phone *might* be missing the profile that's needed to do this.

Comment: Maybe, but it works with other hands-free devices like car radios,so imho it should be possible on a computer too...

Comment: You want your (ubuntu-powered) computer to emulate a bluetooth headset/handsfree device allowing you to use the speakers and mic on the computer as a hands free for your phone? Nice idea and an essential feature if you are building an ubuntu based in-car system.

Answer (score 4):

I know that some bluetooth devices will not connect with a phone I used to have. There seems to be some incompatibilities between different BT devices, and there is not much that could be done there. So far, Bluetooth was more trouble that it was worth it. I also had issues with such keyboards that would always disconnect.

I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but this might be a fact, and unless you can hac the Bluetooth connection, or change bluetooth-related internal settings, you may not be able to do anything.

Comment: Shamesless plug in the most upvoted answer: by now, it just works™ out of the box, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The nohands project seems to be abandoned, but that's no problem:

## It jutst works out of the box with recent (19.10 here) Versions of Ubuntu.

Just pair your computer with the smartphone and configure input and output sound devices accordingly (the default on my laptop was to use the smartphone as input and output which is exactly not what's useful for this scenario). After I changed this to Output: Headphones (Built in audio) and Input: Microphone (Built in audio) it just works.

Comment: How do you install it?

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth is a technology based around specifications and profiles.  According to the official Bluetooth site many features of the core specification are not required, but are optional.  Furthermore, product differentiation is furthered by the use of profiles.

Not all devices support all profiles or are made to support them.  For example, my Motorola Rokr S9 headset supports the Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP), the Headset Profile, and the Hands-Free Profile.  The later two are used for telephone handsfree.

With that said, the first thing to determine is whether your phone and your headphone support the same Core Specification level (ie 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 4.0) and whether or not it supports the proper profiles.  To do so you would need to check with the documentation on the headset and/or with the manufacturer.

If the necessary Profiles or Core Spec is not met, then there is no way to use the computer headset with your mobile.

[Official Bluetooth Technology Info Site](http://www.bluetooth.com)

Answer (score 1):

have you thought about using Google Voice or Skype type applications for your mobile to forward the calls to your PC skype/Voice application?

Comment: Google Voice is only available in US, so I'd need Skype. But I don't see how this could work. Could you explain your thoughts a bit further please?

Comment: With GoogleVoice you use a number that is not the one assigned by your cell phone company. When someone calls that number you can have it ring your computer and your phone at the same time, whichever one picks up first gets the conversation. At any point you can press * on your cell phone and your computer will ring. Once you pick up on your computer Google will connect the two calls and you can hang up your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Hey thank you so much. Because of your post I found HFP for Linux. I was so sick of switching headsets all the time. Anyway, my solution is to use OSS instead of ALSA. Sounds stupid but it works:

- Driver: OSS
- Device: /dev/dsp
- anything else default

I'm using a thinkpad T61p, ubuntu 10.04 with a Nexus One android phone. The whole solution can be found in my blog: http://rebusdigitalis.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-your-phone-from-your-computer-via_15.html

Comment: nice one! I just tried it again, but I'm stuck at connecting (pairing worked, but after that I can't connect to the phone). But as you made it, it gives me new hope! I might play around with it some more...

Comment: i have installed it but the problem is that is is not finding my bluetooth phone please help

Answer (score 0):

i have a HTC tattoo (using android 1.6) and i was able to use my laptop(dell inspiron n 5010) as a bluetooth headset using windows 7. so i know that this is posible with most android phones. what i dont know is if this trick can work on ubuntu

Comment: my phone recognizes my laptop as handsfree... but what application to use to place a call from my laptop (or to answer one)?