# How can I make usual phone calls using a connected mobile phone?

Tags: 10.04, smartphone, headset

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed as a desktop OS and a Symbian-based smartphone (Nokia N79). How can I use my desktop system with a headset to make and receive usual mobile phone calls using a connected (via cable or Bluetooth) smartphone?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too sure that's possible

Comment: You could always try using google voice if you are US based.

Comment: @Marlon, that's slightly not the same thing as I'm asking for.

Comment: Notice I didnt make it an answer, just a comment.  It's not at all what you asked...but since there were no answers and Roland even suggested there might not be one...I figured you could use an alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:
http://nohands.sourceforge.net/

From the website description:

> HFP for Linux is a Bluetooth
>   Hands-Free Profile server.
>
> **It allows your Linux system to act as a speakerphone for your mobile phone.**
>   It aims to be a compliant Bluetooth
>   HFP 1.5 Hands Free implementation,
>   supporting all required commands and
>   notifications, as well as streaming
>   audio.
>
> HFP for Linux was designed
>   specifically for automotive computing
>   applications, but it can be used just
>   as well in a desktop environment.

*You should try it to discover if it's compatible with your device*.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I've asked for! For now It seems to be not stable with my device, but it's better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can install **Hands Free Console** by using [ppa:sebastian-ruehl/nohands](https://launchpad.net/~sebastian-ruehl/+archive/nohands) repository.

There is the list of *packages needed to install*, at [Sourcrforge](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/source.html).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sebastian-ruehl/nohands

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libhfp hfpd hfconsole libaudiofile0 libspeexdsp1 libdbus-1-3 libasound2 subversion g++ autoconf libtool libspeexdsp-dev libasound2-dev libbluetooth-dev libaudiofile-dev libdbus-1-dev
```

Comment: error: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-ruehl/nohands/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found... how to tackle this?

Comment: Beacause You are in Quantral, You need to add the repository as **sudo add-apt-repository "deb 'http://'ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-ruehl/nohands/ubuntu natty main"**.(remove ' ' around http..)That PPA has version only upto Natty.

Comment: it worked, thanks... but nohands is not able to detect my android phone : Samsung Galaxy Chat (B5330)

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5282/use-computer-headset-like-a-hands-free-for-cell-phone). It says that certain Android phones cant connect thisway. Try with installing libimobiledevice packages in [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libimobiledevice)

Comment: sorry to say, but it didn't do.

Comment: It seems better to ask a question regarding your issue.