# bluetooth: call audio loop when paired with phone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 21.10

I have a phone connected to my Ubuntu 21.10 PC via bluetooth, sharing phone calls and media audio. I basically want to use the PC as a headset with access to two-way audio during calls.

Media from the phone is played on the laptop speakers as expected. Blueman shows that the *High Fidelity Capture (A2DP Source)* audio profile is selected.

During a call the profile switches to *Headset Audio Gateway (HSP)*. I do get two-way audio:

- Sounds played on the PC are heard on the call.
- Speakers on the call can be recorded on the PC. **HOWEVER: this input gets echoed back to the callers**.

It seems like call input is treated just like media input: it's played back on whatever output channel is set up. How can I prevent this?

I did try Linux HFP from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16305/how-can-i-make-usual-phone-calls-using-a-connected-mobile-phone), but the project is very old and getting it to compile and run on a modern system isn't easy.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to disable loopback manually during a call. From the PulseAudio [wiki](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/):

> When PulseAudio is acting as a headset... module-bluetooth-policy will also load module-loopback instances to loop the audio from bluetooth to the local speakers and microphone.

So just unloading the module during a call gets rid of the loop effect:

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

This needs to be done every time. It's possible to prevent it from loading in the first place by passing the `hfgw` argument to `module-bluetooth-policy` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-bluetooth-policy hfgw=false
```

Unfortunately this also disables playback of media audio. Is there a way to only do it for calls?